# MySQL - can I avoid these correlated / dependent subqueries?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

I have been optimising a MySQL query, and it has 2 correlated / dependent subqueries.

How can I rewrite to avoid these?

```
SELECT *
FROM `pp_slides` 
JOIN `pp_slide_content` 
    ON `pp_slides`.`id` = `pp_slide_content`.`slide_id` 
    AND `pp_slide_content`.`version` = (
        SELECT max(`version`)
        FROM `pp_slide_content`
        WHERE `slide_id` = `pp_slides`.`id`
    )
LEFT JOIN `pp_published_slides` 
    ON `pp_published_slides`.`slide_id` = `pp_slides`.`id` 
    AND `pp_published_slides`.`slide_version` = `pp_slide_content`.`version` 
    AND `pp_published_slides`.`publish_id` = (
        SELECT max(`publish_id`)
        FROM `pp_published_slides`
        WHERE `pp_published_slides`.`slide_id` = `pp_slides`.`id`
        AND `pp_published_slides`.`slide_version` = `pp_slide_content`.`version`
    )
LEFT JOIN `pp_publish`
    ON `pp_publish`.`id` = `publish_id`
WHERE `pp_slides`.`product_id` =  '2'
AND `pp_slides`.`country_code` =  'gb'
```

A quick overview:
A slide is created, and supports versioned changes.
A slide (and other entities) is then published.
The slide and the version that is published is set in the pp_published_slides tables.
And the overall published object is saved in pp_publish.

The above SQL will load up a slide object and include extra data about the latest version, when it was published, etc.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/902fb4/1

Comment: Matt please update what you want to achieve i.e. what result you want from these queries. So that there can be a different way altogether.

Comment: Do not use "SELECT *". Name and properly qualify each of the columns that you actually want returned.

Comment: Beyond that, these do seem to be two different queries. Are you sure it's legitimate to combine them as one? If so, then consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I don't use SELECT *, this is a simplified version for the purposes of the post - ill update in a bit with some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example showing part of your query rewritten without the correlated subquery...

```
SELECT s.*
     , c.*
  FROM slides s  
  JOIN slide_content c
    ON c.slide_id = s.id
  JOIN ( SELECT slide_id, MAX(version) max_version FROM slide_content GROUP BY slide_id ) x
    ON x.slide_id = c.slide_id
   AND x.max_version = c.version 
 WHERE s.product_id = 2
   AND s.country_code = 'gb';
```