# MySQL query performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL database and 5 tables called `tribes(groups)`, `posts`, `posts_to_groups`, `post_comments` and `posts_votes`.

Relationship between groups and posts is MANY_2_MANY so each post can belong to many groups and each group can contain 0-* posts. This is what table posts_to_groups does.

I'm searching for the 3 most popular posts that were posted into the groups that this user follows(associated via posts_to_tribes - table for MANY_2_MANY relationship) for the last 24 hours from this moment and ordered by sum of (comments_count + votes_count) DESC

This is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.post_id,
    p.description,
    p.link,
    p.user_id,
    p.total_comments,
    p.total_votes,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            comments
        WHERE
            last_edited > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                AND post_id = p.post_id) AS comments_count,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            posts_votes
        WHERE
            date_voted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                AND post_id = p.post_id) AS votes_count
FROM
    posts p
        JOIN
    posts_to_tribes pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE
    pt.tribe_id IN (3 , 38, 107)
ORDER BY (comments_count + votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This query is extremely slow and took right now **~500ms**.

Is any way to rewrite this query in order to improve performance ?

**UPDATED:**

EXPLAIN output:

[image]

Query suggested by **Tim3880**:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.description,
    p.link,
    p.user_id,
    p.total_comments,
    p.total_votes,
    t.comments_count,
    t.votes_count
FROM posts p
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        p.post_id,
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                comments
            WHERE
                last_edited > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                    AND post_id = p.post_id) AS comments_count,
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                posts_votes
            WHERE
                date_voted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                    AND post_id = p.post_id) AS votes_count
    FROM
        posts p
            JOIN
        posts_to_tribes pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
    WHERE
        pt.tribe_id IN (3 , 38, 107)
    ORDER BY (comments_count + votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ON p.post_id = t.post_id
ORDER BY (t.comments_count + t.votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
```

It took now **~280ms**.

EXPLAIN output:

[image]

Comment: Please add the result of a `EXPLAIN SELECT...` from your query together with your table definition.

Comment: What is the `EXPLAIN` output? Do you have indexes on the columns you are using in the `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! Unfortunately I have no access to this db right now, I'll provide this information tomorrow.

Comment: Without execution plan, we can only guess. You can try rewrite your sub queries using group by post id and then join them for the outer query.

Comment: 500 ms does not seem particularly slow, particularly if the underlying tables have a lot of data.  What is your expectation.

Comment: we have a lot of different queries(inside of REST endpoints) and only this one under performance testing shows ~16 sec(in concurrent environment) while the other endpoints show ~2 or 3 sec

Comment: I have added EXPLAIN output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post_id is a primary key (or unique), try get the 3 post_id first:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.description,
    p.link,
    p.user_id,
    p.total_comments,
    p.total_votes,
    t.comments_count,
    t.votes_count
FROM posts p 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        p.post_id,
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                comments
            WHERE
                last_edited > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                    AND post_id = p.post_id) AS comments_count,
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                posts_votes
            WHERE
                date_voted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                    AND post_id = p.post_id) AS votes_count
    FROM
        posts p
            JOIN
        posts_to_tribes pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
    WHERE
        pt.tribe_id IN (3 , 38, 107)
        AND p.last_edited >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    ORDER BY (comments_count + votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ON p.post_id = t.post_id
ORDER BY (t.comments_count + t.votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
```

Edit:  This is the join version:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.description,
    p.link,
    p.user_id,
    p.total_comments,
    p.total_votes,
    t.comments_count,
    t.votes_count
FROM posts p 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        p.post_id,Comments_Count, Votes_Count
    FROM
        posts p
        JOIN
        posts_to_tribes pt ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                post_id, COUNT(*) Comments_Count
            FROM
                comments
            WHERE
                last_edited > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
            GROUP BY post_id) cc
        ON p.post_id = cc.post_id
        LEFT JOIN 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                post_id, COUNT(*) Votes_Count
            FROM
                posts_votes
            WHERE
                date_voted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
            GROUP BY post_id
        ) vc
        ON p.post_id = vc.post_id
        WHERE pt.tribe_id IN (3 , 38, 107)
    ORDER BY (comments_count + votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ON p.post_id = t.post_id
ORDER BY (t.comments_count + t.votes_count) DESC , p.last_edited DESC
```

If the performance is still not acceptable, you may have to think about updating the total_comments, total_votes directly or using trigger or scheduled job.

Comment: Thanks, this is the fastest query.. but it shows the other output results than the original one..

Comment: It works 2 times faster than the original query.. but the speed is still not perfect. May be correlated subqueries here can also be optimized ?

Comment: Your explain output didn't indicate any sub query issues. Please post your new explain result.

Comment: Added explain output for your query

Comment: As I said, the plan didn't show any sub query issues. group by may make it worse.

Comment: Also, I already use  total_comments and  total_votes but for total comments/votes number for all time.. but inside of this query I need to find posts based on some sliding interval (now - x). This is why I need to calculate this on the fly with subselects or something similar..

Comment: I don't have the data to play around. If I have to dig further, I would try 1) add the time filter to the posts 2) try different composite indexes.

Comment: I added  the line " AND p.last_edited >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)". On my testing environment, it makes huge difference.

Comment: Thanks Tim3880! Right now this query runs ~156ms. Tomorrow I'll run my performance tests and report a results here.

Comment: The last query shows the best results. Thanks Tim3880!

Answer (score 0):

You have used 2 [correlated subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html). Each one from the correlated subqueries will be executed once for every row from the outer query. Hence, if you can avoid them it's likely to get faster query.

> [..] they are inefficient and likely to be slow. Rewriting the query as a join might improve performance.

You have to avoid them by using join. This may help you: [MySQL - can I avoid these correlated / dependant subqueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278054/mysql-can-i-avoid-these-correlated-dependant-subqueries)

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me with this query ?